# Different types of correlation query

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery

I have my query and I need to get the same output with a correlated subquery. I'm new in the correlated subqueries, so please help.

The original query:

```
SELECT Sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID, SUM(Sales.SalesOrderDetail.LineTotal)
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
    INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    ON Sales.SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID
GROUP BY Sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID;
```

Comment: Test database - https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/downloads/get/880661

Comment: My query has 19119 output rows.

Comment: " I need to write any kind of correlation with the same output." What?

Comment: Any kind of correlation query.

Comment: Sorry, my bad English -  I need to get the same output with a correlated subquery

Comment: Gotcha. You want to convert this INNER JOIN to a correlated subquery. I don't know that it's possible since you have both `SalesOrderDetail` and `SalesOrderHeader` fields in your result set. Fields from a table that is only brought in through a correlated subquery are not available for the result set. Why is that you need to convert this query if it's working as-is?

Comment: I need to investigate this query (and all its possible forms). I need to compare the cost, implementation plans, time.

Comment: I understand that, but can I write this query in a different form? I understand that, but can I write this query in a different form? The use of two tables in 'FROM' already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for all the back and forth in the comments. Using a correlated subquery in the SELECT portion of the query, you could write this, also, as:

```
SELECT customerID, sum(sumOfLines)
FROM
    (
        SELECT header.CustomerID, 
            (SELECT sum(Detail.LineTotal) FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail.LineTotal as Detail WHERE Detail.SalesOrderID = header.SalesOrderID) as sumOfLines
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID as header
    ) sub
GROUP BY customerID
```

This is pretty ugly and is not going to perform faster. There is a fairly good chance your DBMS will choose the same execution path for both version.

---

Update: I updated the above sql to aggregate again by using a subquery so that only unique customerID's come through, since we can't aggregate on a correlated subquery within the query that utilizes the correlated subquery.

Comment: I am a little-corrected error in the query. He returns 31465 rows. It contains duplicate customers.

Comment: SELECT header.CustomerID, 
    (SELECT sum(Detail.LineTotal) FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail as Detail WHERE Detail.SalesOrderID = header.SalesOrderID) as sumOfLines
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader as header;

Comment: That makes sense. Your Header table has duplicate customers... I should have thought of that. I'm updating the answer. I believe you can aggregate on the results returned from the correlated subquery. Again, I think this will end up with worse performance than your original very clean query.

Comment: I know and understand that, but my goal - to explore it and write my diploma work. I will be waiting for your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Got it. I'm just stressing it because SO is a Q&A site that others use to solve their problem by referring to already asked questions. I don't want someone getting the idea that a correlated subquery written in such a way is in anyway a better solution over your original query. It's like reinventing the wheel, but instead of a round wheel on a metal axle, you make a square wheel suspended with rope. The cart may roll, but it's going to be a bumpy ride.

Comment: No, last edit is impossible. I use MS SQL Server 2014. :)

Comment: Darn!  ok... back to the drawing board.  - I've updated the answer again to stick the Query with the Correlated Subquery into a subquery of it's own. Then we aggregate again in the main query to get a unique customerID and it's sum of lines.

Comment: Magic, hurray! New query contains fewer logical reads and cheaper execution plan. Haha.

Comment: That is magical! I trusted SQL server too. For shame. I would still yell at someone if they handed me that query. It's so ugly.